# iOS xcode Why my lib.a exists in bundle file, ipa file?

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle

I use 3rd party lib.a for almost 2 years. And this lib.a can be accepted by Appstore.
    However, I made some modification and submitted new version to app store.
    xcode shows error when verification. 
    Here's the error.
  Invalid Bundle structure- The binary file 'my.app/lib.a' is not permitted. Your app may contain only one executable file. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/conceptual/cfbundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html...... 
  And after I remove lib.a from my bundle, it can upload to app-store correctly.
  Besides, after removing lib.a my bundle , I test it via testflight and it works fine.
  Therefore, it seems this lib.a file can be removed from xcode, but I don't know how to remove it.
  lib.a may statically linked with my.app (main executable.).

If I remove it from xcode, it will show link error.
  Please share that how to remove it in archived file via xcode without linking error. 
  Currently, I manually remove lib.a after archiving. It's time-consuming and I'm afraid something is wrong.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store support, not a programming issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I accidentally add lib.a into project.pbxproj. (It doesn't show up in Xcode UI.)

After I removed it, the lib.a was gone in the bundle file.

And it can be submitted to Appstore correctly.

On other hand, it used to be OK to submit bundle file with lib.a.

Maybe Appstore changed its rule. No lib.a in bundle file anymore.

Hope this help other people.